# Javascript calculation not giving desired output

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
 function calculateVat() {
        var vat = null;var amount=null;
        vat = document.getElementById("hiddenvat").value;           
        amount = document.getElementById("numtxt_itemCost").value;
        var total = parseInt(amount)* parseInt(vat) / 100 ;
        
        document.getElementById("txt_Total_text").value = total;
    }
```

Here I am calculating VAT price according to amount price

**E.G.** VAT value is 13.5

If I input 1780 on `numtxt_itemCost` Field  then it should give the output 240.30,
but when I run this programme by putting value 1780 on `numtxt_itemCost` field
it shows the 231.4  which is the wrong output,

Comment: Well, `parseInt('13.5')` results in `13`, since you want to convert the string to an *integer*. You probably want `parseFloat`. I recommend to use the unary `+` operator instead though.

Comment: Also you could use `toFixed(2)` if you want `240.30` and not `240.3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `parseFloat` instead:

```
parseFloat(1780)* parseFloat(13.5) / 100 //240.3
```

when you use `parseInt`, all decimals get stripped off.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function calculateVat() {
        var vat = null;var amount=null;
        vat = document.getElementById("hiddenvat").value;           
        amount = document.getElementById("numtxt_itemCost").value;
        var total = parseInt(amount)* parseFloat(vat) / 100 ;

        document.getElementById("txt_Total_text").value = total;
    }
```

The problem is that you were converting the vat to an "int" using `parseInt(vat)`, so the answer you were seeing was the result of a 13% vat rather than 13.5%.